# How to add a legend box with an expanded color pallete using R rworldmap?

Tags: r, rworldmap

I plotted a map using rworldmap. But I couldn't insert a legend with an expanded color pallete. I got this error:

> Error in legend(....  unused arguments (colourVector1 = "#00008B",
>   colourVector2 = "#0B0B90", ...

Here is my code:

```
library(rworldmap)
#color pallete
colours = colorRampPalette(c("darkblue", "white"))(23)

#csvfile
dF = read.csv("/home/shops.csv", header = T)

sPDF <- joinCountryData2Map(dF,
                            joinCode = "NAME",
                            nameJoinColumn = "Country",
                            verbose = TRUE)
mapData = mapCountryData(
  sPDF,
  nameColumnToPlot="Shops",
  mapTitle = "Number of facilities around the world",
  addLegend = F
  )
do.call( addMapLegendBoxes, c(mapData, cex=0.39,  x="left", colourVector = colours))
```

Here is part of my csv file:

```
           Country Shops
1  United States   302
2        Germany    77
3 United Kingdom    67
4          Spain    60
5         France    44
6          China    35
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by myself using ggmap. This was the solution:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggmap)
library(parallel)

#set workspace
setwd("/home/")
#Load data
df = read.csv("shops.csv", header = T)
coords = mclapply(X = as.character(df$Country), FUN= function(x) geocode(x))
coords=do.call(rbind.data.frame,coords)
df$lon = coords$lon
df$lat = coords$lat

mapWorld <- borders("world", colour="#E7E7E7", fill="#1a0000", alpha = .5)
mp <- ggplot() + mapWorld

mp <- mp+ geom_point(aes(x=df$lon, y=df$lat, size=df$Shops), alpha = .9, color="#000033")
mp <- mp + labs(size= "Number of shops")
mp <- mp + scale_size_continuous(breaks=c(5, 15, 26, 35, 44, 60, 67, 77, 302))
mp <- mp + theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
                 axis.text.x=element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks.x=element_blank(),
                 axis.title.y=element_blank(),
                 axis.text.y=element_blank(),
                 axis.ticks.y=element_blank())
mp
```

Csv file:

```
    Country Shops
1  United States   302
2        Germany    77
3 United Kingdom    67
4          Spain    60
5         France    44
6          China    35
...
```

[image: Plot]